# How to access current process objects from Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, iis-7.5

I have a scenario where the existing website is tied up to the server's hardware via license.  I haven't got the source code for that site.

I need to develop a number of custom controls to that website. Ideally, I would like to have access to the existing website process object such as current user etc.

I know how to do remote debuging of the web app, but I need to use the process for development of my project.

Is there a way in VisualStudio develop new functionality to attached process.

I have spent some time googling, but I possibly formulate the query wrong.

Comment: You want to debug a process or application with visual studio ?

Comment: @Midhun I need to debug my app using the session of the existing web app if that makes sense.